# how to fetch data when a single column contains values from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I know it's kind of a confusing question so let me first explain the scenario.

The scenario is:

there are 3 tables

1. `service_master (id, name, cost, duration, visit_count, remarks)`
2. `product_master (id, name, cost)`
3. `sell (id, item_id, item_type)`

so, in **`sell`** table

**`id`** goes for the `primary key`,

**`item_id`** has data from 2 tables (`product_master` and `service_master`)

**`item_type`** will be use to recognize if the item is a `service` or a `product` (`P, S`)

so the issue is when I want to fetch all the sold item for the user how will I get the name of item instead of the `ID`es

Please suggest what should I do and if I am doing it wrong then please correct me.

So many thanks in advace !!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help to answer your queston

Comment: Also, what did you try so far? Did you try `SELECT` with `JOIN` in SQL? Post your code.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Do you have unique IDs over both product and service table, or do the IDs overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IDs are unique over both, the service and the product table, (perhaps by using a sequence) you could just:

```
SELECT
  sell.id sell_id
  , sell.item_type
  , item_detail.id
  , item_detail.name
  , item_detail.cost
FROM sell
JOIN
  (SELECT id, name, cost FROM service_master
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, name, cost FROM product_master
  ) item_detail
  ON sell.item_id = item_detail.id
;
```

Otherwise, you have another option (in addition to the ones suggested by Thorsten Kettner and DhruvJoshi), which you might want to test for performance implications, if your tables are large - but you want to retrieve the data for a very small subset (e.g.: a single invoice):

```
SELECT
  id sell_id
  , CASE item_type
    WHEN 'P'
    THEN (SELECT name FROM product_master WHERE sell.item_id = id)
    WHEN 'S'
    THEN (SELECT name FROM service_master WHERE sell.item_id = id)
    END AS item_name
FROM sell
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb910/1)

#### Update

There is a way of simply joining the tables - which even works for overlapping IDs:

```
SELECT
  sell.id sell_id
  , sell.item_type
  , item_detail.id
  , item_detail.name
  , item_detail.cost
FROM sell2 sell
JOIN
  (SELECT 'S' flag, id, name, cost FROM service_master2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'P', id, name, cost FROM product_master2
  ) item_detail
  ON sell.item_type = item_detail.flag
  AND sell.item_id = item_detail.id
;
```

See this in comparison: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3616ac/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: thank you so much. the second one is working like a charm. I was using Dhruv's way to do the task but know you have really improvised the statement and now it can work with more tables than 2. thanks Abecee and @DhruvJoshi

Comment: Just keep in mind, the potential performance issue. If you wanted to extend DhruvJoshi's approach to more tables, `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL` should do the trick. Personally, I'd probably prefer IDs, which are unique over all the relevant tables. But if you do have existing data, which does not satisfy this condition, you have now some options to choose from...

Answer (score 1):

*How* to select depends on *what* you want to select of course :-)

Here is an example on how to select all data:

```
select s.*, sm.name, sm.cost, sm.duration
from sell s
join service_master sm on sm.id = s.item_id
where s.item_type = 'SERVICE'
union all
select s.*, pm.name, pm.cost, null
from sell s
join product_master pm on pm.id = s.item_id
where s.item_type = 'PRODUCT';
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you need logic like below:

```
Select * from Sell S 
left join Service_master SM on S.item_id =SM.id and S.item_type like 'S'
left join Prodcut_master PM on S.item_id =PM.id and S.item_type like 'P'
```

use case condition in `select` part if you want to return name as single like

```
Select ISNULL(SM.name,PM.name) as name from Sell S 
left join Service_master SM on S.item_id =SM.id and S.item_type like 'S'
left join Prodcut_master PM on S.item_id =PM.id and S.item_type like 'P'
```

Comment: I am a little confuse. Should I go with your answer or the one that Thorsten Kettner has given...

Comment: `UNION` is one way to do it and optimised `LEFT JOIN` is another way to do it.  Since your Service_master and Product_master tables are different in terms of structure I'd advise you to use `JOIN`s. So that you consciously use correct data in the select list. Marking any as answer is your prerogative, however I can tell you both answers work. Please do consider upvoting answers which work for you or tell you something new.

Comment: Thank you DhruvJoshi I was implementing your answer but @Abecee has enhanced your statement like a charm so now going to implement his answer. I do not know how to thank you both you both have saved me from the pit of hell.. so thank you from the bottom of my heart. god bless you